# stripe custom success page client side

Tags: stripe-payments, payment-gateway, payment

In the documentation they show how to do it with server-side, however, I'm using a shared hosting so I can't install the webhook libraries or server-side libraries (node, php or whatever). I want to do it manually, but I don't know if there's a way for that. The idea is to send the query (post or get) to my successpage and from there read what was sent or any workaround to validate payment and take an automatic action.

Thanks,

Comment: Can you edit your question to include a lot more specific detail? Can you confirm you're talking about [Stripe Checkout](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout)? You mentioned you can't install server-side libraries, but it also sounds like you want to write code somewhere to do something?

Comment: I'm talking about stripe checkout, and I obviously can write code but their tutorials include installing node.js or php libraries which you cannot do in a shared hosting

Comment: If you can't write server-side code I'm not sure what kind of success page customization is practical.  Can you provide more details about what you want on the success page?

Comment: any info such as any code, or email address of the buyer (it's usually included in the customer info but without server side I'm not sure If I can get such info)

Comment: That's not really going to be possible using just client-side code.